# Understanding the Importance of the Borel-Cantelli Lemma

Tags: probability

The Borel-Cantelli Lemma states that:

- **Lemma 1:** If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(E_n) < \infty$ then $P(\limsup E_n) = 0$
- **Lemma 2:** If $\{E_n\}$ are independent and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(E_n) = \infty$ then $P(\limsup E_n) = 1$

As I understand, "lim sup" can be understood in the following ways:

- For the sequence $a_n = (-1)^n$ ,   $\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n = 1$. This is because as $n$ becomes larger, $a_n  =1$
- For the sequence $b_n = \frac{1}{n}$,  $\limsup_{n \to \infty} b_n = 0$. This is because as $n$ becomes larger, $b_n  =0$

Going back to the Borel-Cantelli Lemma, here is my understanding of it:

Suppose we have a single 6 sided fair die. We denote our event of interest to be rolling a 6. Naturally, there is a $1/6$ probability of rolling a 6. This means that every 6 rolls we would expect to see the number 6 once on average. If we roll the die an infinite number of times, the probability of getting an infinite number of 6's is 0.

I suppose one could say that in an infinite number of rolls, we should see an infinite number of 6's. But I think this is where the concept of cardinality and countable infinites comes in. Yes, we would see an infinite number of 6's in infinite rolls, but this infinite would be dwarfed by the infinite corresponding to the total number of infinite rolls. Thus, the probability of seeing an infinite number of 6's in infinite rolls is 0.

Is this the correct understanding of Borel-Cantelli? Can someone please help me think of some small toy examples/ computer simulations (e.g. Python, R) that can be used to demonstrate the Borel-Cantelli lemma?

Comment: If $E_n$ is the event "on $n'$th roll you get $6$", then events $\{E_n\}_n$ are independent (assuming the independence of rolls, but otherwise we would need to state how they depend on themselves) and, moreover, $\sum_n \mathbb P(E_n) = \sum_n \frac{1}{6} = +\infty$, so from the second B-C lemma $\mathbb P(\limsup E_n) = 1$, i.e. with probability $1$ you shall see infinitely many $6$'s in infinite rolls, which is quite intuitive, isn't it? The behaviour of $6$ is the same as behaviour of any of $1,2,...,5$. And of course, you shall see infinite amount of at least one of those numbers.

Comment: @ Presage: Thank you for your answer! Is the example I gave correct?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe more interesting examples are these.

1. At step $n$ you roll an $n$-sided die, i.e. take a random integer from $1$ to $n$, independently.  The probability of getting a $1$ at step $n$ is thus $1/n$.  Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n = \infty$, Borel-Cantelli #2 says with probability $1$ you will get infinitely many $1$'s.
2. Similar to the above, except that you roll an $n^2$-sided die. Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^2 < \infty$, Borel-Cantelli #1 says with probability $1$ you will get only finitely many $1$'s.

Comment: @ Robert Israel: Thank you for your answer! Is the example I gave correct?

Comment: No.  "If we roll the die an infinite number of times, the probability of getting an infinite number of 6's is 0" is wrong.  That probability is $1$, as stated in Borel-Cantelli # 2.